# R: replacing values in the randomly selected fractions of observations

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I am relatively new to R and probably the solution to this problem is rather simple.

Let's imagine that i have nest dataset of bird two species (a and b) like this:

```
df
year nestid sp  egg chick
2013    a1  a   2   1
2013    a2  a   NA  1
2013    a3  a   NA  0
2013    a4  a   NA  1
2013    a5  a   NA  0
2013    b1  b   2   0
2013    b2  b   NA  1
2013    b3  b   NA  2
2013    b4  b   NA  1
2014    a1  a   NA  1
2014    a2  a   NA  1
2014    a3  a   1   1
2014    a4  a   NA  1
2014    a5  a   NA  1
2014    b1  b   NA  1
2014    b2  b   NA  2
2014    b3  b   NA  2
2014    b4  b   NA  1
```

I want to infer number of eggs for those 'NAs' from number of chicks. It makes sense to replace "NA" by 2 if there were "2" chicks as they lay 2 eggs max.

But i want to replace NAs by "2" for randomly selected 80% of nests with 1 chick and replace by "1" for remaining 20% of the nests with 1 chick for species "a" in year 2013. But this ratio would be 40% and 60% for clutch sizes of 2 and 1 respectively for species "a" in 2014.

I tried like this but could not work out how to code properly.

```
df%>% mutate(egg=ifelse(egg==0 & chick==2, 2, egg))

df%>% 
mutate(egg=ifelse(egg==0 & chick==1 & year==2013, sample_frac(.8)==2, egg))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: `dput` your data and paste it `dput(df)`, so that someone can use your data as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approach could be

```r
set.seed(123)

#missing egg & chick = 2
df$egg <- with(df,ifelse(is.na(egg) & chick == 2, 2, egg))

#2013 data having species = 'a', missing egg & chick = 1
x <- with(df, which(is.na(egg) & chick == 1 & sp == 'a' & year == 2013))
x_sample <- sample(x, round(0.8 * length(x)))
df$egg[x_sample] <- 2
df$egg[setdiff(x, x_sample)] <- 1

#2014 data having species = 'a', missing egg & chick = 1
x <- with(df, which(is.na(egg) & chick == 1 & sp == 'a' & year == 2014))
x_sample <- sample(x, round(0.4 * length(x)))
df$egg[x_sample] <- 2
df$egg[setdiff(x, x_sample)] <- 1
```

which gives

```
> df
   year nestid sp egg chick
1  2013     a1  a   2     1
2  2013     a2  a   2     1
3  2013     a3  a  NA     0
4  2013     a4  a   2     1
5  2013     a5  a  NA     0
6  2013     b1  b   2     0
7  2013     b2  b  NA     1
8  2013     b3  b   2     2
9  2013     b4  b  NA     1
10 2014     a1  a   1     1
11 2014     a2  a   2     1
12 2014     a3  a   1     1
13 2014     a4  a   2     1
14 2014     a5  a   1     1
15 2014     b1  b  NA     1
16 2014     b2  b   2     2
17 2014     b3  b   2     2
18 2014     b4  b  NA     1
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L), nestid = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", 
"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", 
"b3", "b4"), sp = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"), egg = c(2L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), chick = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("year", "nestid", "sp", 
"egg", "chick"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now, i was stacked but am able to move on with my coding.